# Can you pass NavHostController to a child Composable in order to allow access to the navController.navigate("Route")?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am new to Jetpack Compose and am struggling to understand how to integrate the Navigation library with Compose.
I have successfully implemented a bottom navigation, but now and struggling to access the .navigate("route") method in a child component. Should I be passing in the navController as a param from the composeable inside the NavHost? Here is my code to make things more clear.

Here is my HomeScreen.kt @Composable which invokes the rememberNavController() method as well as the NavHost() composable as follows...

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
val navController = rememberNavController()
...
Scaffold(
   ...
) {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "route") {
        composable("route") { Settings(navController) }
  } 
}
```

So here you can see i'm passing the navController as a param to the Settings composable. I'm not sure if this is correct. Now, ultimately from within the Settings composable i'd like to access the **navController.navigate("route")** method if possible, similar to the following.

```
@Composable
fun Settings(navController: NavHostController) {
   ...
   Button(onClick = {navController.navigate("route")}) {
        Text(text = "button text")
    }
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot access the .navigate method as it says "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied." Thanks for the time and help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navigate("route")` method is [an extension method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/compose/package-summary#navigate). Therefore you must explicitly import it:

```
import androidx.navigation.compose.navigate
```

Comment: Note there's an [open issue against Android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172834438) trying to get to the bottom of why Studio does not automatically recommend importing this extension.

Comment: WOW! Thanks so much. If you were near i'd give you a kiss! (worked btw).... and yes I was definitely relying too much on Android Studio prompting me to import the extension.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Make sure to [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions. Best of luck going forward!

Answer (score 1):

You *can* pass in the navController like you are doing in your code, but it would be better to make the event a parameter to the Setting screen compostable and pass in the function to navigate wherever the navHost is declared. This will follow the single source of truth principle and make it easier to test... see the documentation about navigation events from Google.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

> MyAppNavHost composable function as the single source of truth for the NavController instance. ProfileScreen exposes an event as a function that is called when the user taps on a button. MyAppNavHost, which owns navigating to the different screens in the app, makes the navigation call to the right destination when calling ProfileScreen.

```
    @Composable
fun MyAppNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = "profile"
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable("profile") {
            ProfileScreen(
                onNavigateToFriends = { navController.navigate("friendsList") },
                /*...*/
            )
        }
        composable("friendslist") { FriendsListScreen(/*...*/) }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(
    onNavigateToFriends: () -> Unit,
    /*...*/
) {
    /*...*/
    Button(onClick = onNavigateToFriends) {
        Text(text = "See friends list")
    }
}
```